# Should I try to treat a Majesty palm tree with brown holes in the leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, pruning, palm

I purchased a Majesty palm tree, but didn't realize till after I repotted it, that it had lots of brown holes in some of the leaves.

Should I prune the damaged leaves or should I just return the tree for another one?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Was this plant outside? That looks like insect damage: https://www.google.com/search?q=grasshopper+damage+corn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=m9KJVN-COo2uyASAyIDgCg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=949&bih=500#tbm=isch&q=grasshopper+damage+palm

Comment: @ Wayfaring Stranger I purchased this from lowe's this was outside when on sale. However, as you can see from the pic its a home plant for me :) I wanted to know know if i shoild prun the damaged leafs or just return them. and look more thourgh before buying the new plant

Comment: so I had this repotted and removed all leafs that had any damages, watered it and now its waitting time to see if i did a good job

Comment: Hi Joseph! Now that it's been a few months since you treated your plant, I'm wondering how it's doing. If you have a minute for an update, that would be great. I hope it's healthy and happy!

Comment: @Sue  unfortunately I repotted this in a wrong soil and it just went downhill. I'm planning to get another one this summer

Comment: Hi Joseph-sorry it took me so long to reply! I'm sorry about the loss of this plant, and hope you got a new one and that it's doing well!

Answer (score 2):

Lowe's warranties their plants for one year from date of purchase. Go trade for another one. It's a gonner.